# Writing to MS Access files on/via Rails app hosted on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ms-access, heroku, odbc

I'm trying to determine whether it's possible to write to an MS Access mdb file using a rails app hosted on heroku?

I'm guessing ODBC is the way to go, but am not sure of which gem etc as well as where to temporarily stick the mdb file while the rails app is operating on it.

The end result is I want to upload a csv and an access file and have the rails app import bits of the data into certain spots of the access file, then spit the edited mdb file back to the user as a download.

Any thoughts on how to attack this?

Comment: re: In the same request; 'yes' is my uninformed answer (i know it will take a few minutes), but it sounds like you're saying it should be a 'no'? If so do you mind outlining how you think it should be done?

Comment: Thanks anyway mu is too short. Anyone else?